# Display Image Based on URL Ending (Variable or Attribute) [Pound/Number Sign # ]

Tags: javascript, url

I need an image to be displayed based on the ending of a URL.

For example, I need "123.jpg" to be displayed when someone visits:

> - website.com/view/#123
> - website.com/view/#123.jpg
> - website.com/view#123
> - website.com/view#123.jpg

(whichever is recommended or would actually work)

I'm looking for the end result to be: `< img src=123.jpg" >`

Thanks in advance. I will sincerely appreciate any assistance.

(By way of background or additional information, I need this for Facebook's sharer.php so that people can share one of hundreds of images on a given webpage (for example, website.com/blog and they happen to love the 123rd image on there), they click the link to share that specific image (123.jpg), and then any of their friends who clicks on the link (website.com/view/#123) will arrive at a themed page with just the image in the middle (123.jpg) and nothing else, and then they can click around the rest of the website. The main benefit is that 123.jpg will be the only image that shows up as a thumbnail on the Facebook Feed or "Wall".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (location.hash) {
         var url = location.hash.substr(1); // strip the # char
         if (url.indexOf('.') == -1) {
             url += '.jpg';
         }
         document.getElementById('myImg').src = url; // show the image; value of the variable 'url'
    }
};
window.onhashchange(); // call the event on load
```

Comment: How do I call/invoke this into < img src >? Thank you!

Comment: `document.getElementById('myImg').src = url;`

Comment: I'm sorry- I still don't understand. What would the entire html code look like? I don't have a lot of experience.

Comment: If you have `<img id="myImg" />` in the HTML code, my JS snippet in the previous comment will set the `src` attribute to the URL.

Comment: It's still not working :-( Here's what I did: <html>  
<head>  
</head>  

<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
window.onhashchange = function() {  
    if (location.hash) {  
         var url = location.hash.substr(1); // strip the # char  
         if (url.indexOf('.') == -1) {  
             url += '.jpg';  
         }  
         // show the image; value of the variable 'url'  
    }  
};  
window.onhashchange(); // call the event on load  
</script>  
  
<script type="text/javascript">  
document.getElementById('myImg').src = url;  
</script>  
<img id="myImg" >  
</body>  
</html>

Comment: You need to place the `document.getElementById` line where i have the `//show the image` comment,

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the only one I was able to get to work. I'm very grateful to you. You have a very bright future ahead! I wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = document.URL; //get the url

   if ( url.indexOf("#") != -1 ) //check if '#' is present in the url 
   {
      var split_array = url.split("#");
      var image_url = split_array[split_array.length - 1];

      //display the image
   }
});
```

Comment: How do I call/invoke this into < img src >? Thank you!

Comment: Create an empty section in your page like `<div id = "img_div"></div>` in the body. Do `$("#img_div").append('<img src = "'+ image_url +'"/>');`

Comment: I'm sorry, I still do not understand.  Like this?

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

   var url = document.URL; //get the url



   if ( url.indexOf("#") != -1 ) //check if '#' is present in the url 

   {

      var split_array = url.split("#");

      var image_url = split_array[split_array.length - 1];



      //display the image

   }

});

$("#img_div").append('<img src = "'+ image_url +'"/>');

</script>

</head>



<body>

<div id = "img_div"></div>

</body>

</html>

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    getImageSrc();
    $(window).on('hashchange',  getImageSrc); // will always lookout for changes in # URL

  });

  function getImageSrc() {
    if(window.location.hash) {
        var imgSrc = window.location.hash.substr(1);
        if(imgSrc.indexOf('.') == -1 ) {
            imgSrc = imgSrc + ".jpg";
        }
        alert(imgSrc);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do I call/invoke this into < img src >? Thank you!

Comment: Just change the image selector with jquery .attr('src', 'imgSrc');

Comment: I'm sorry- I still don't understand. What would the entire html code look like? I don't have a lot of experience.